# Get value of all column from one table and get value of other column from second table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to get result from my database.

I have two table "travels" and "airlines" and I want to get result of all the columns from travels table which is ("id","name","airline_name","price","via") and from second table which is airlines based on the columns("id","name","logo").

I want to get "logo" whose name is the same as airline_name in the travel table.

What should I do? Should I used join?? So far my query is:

```
 $this->db->select();
 $this->db->from('travels');
 $this->db->join('airlines', 'travels.airline_name = airlines.name','inner');
 $this->db->group_by('travels.destination');
```

I am using CodeIgniter.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it right: The field "logo" from airlines has the same value as "airline_name" from travel table? Or you mean the "name" has the same value as "airline_name" and you want to get the Logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t.id,
  t.name,
  t.airline_name,
  t.price,
  t.via,
  a.logo
FROM travels AS t
  INNER JOIN airlines AS a ON (t.airline_name = a.logo);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Having doubt that the extension of logo image not match with airline name.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Model Function.and Get it to your controller

and Foreach in on your view

```
$this->db->select('t.id','t.name','t.airline_name','t.price','t.via', 'a.logo as a_logo')
```

;
    $this->db->join('airlines a', 'a.logo = t.airline_name');

```
$query = $this->db->get('travels t');
$query->return->result_array();
```

Comment: EDIT 

$this->db-> select ( 'p.id' , 'p.name', 'a.logo as airlinelogo');
$this->db->join( 'airlines a' , a.logo = p.airline_name');
$query = $this->db-> get ('travel p');
$query-> return ->result_array();